# The numpy array (ndarray) cannot be specified as an output layer

Tags: onnx, openvino

I tried to edit my Yolo-v7 model outputs and add a constant output tensor ( the number of bounding boxes). But when I run conversion to TF I got

```
WARNING: The numpy array (ndarray) cannot be specified as an output layer. Therefore, the tool outputs a sequentially numbered .npy binary file. .npy_file_path: tf_output/0.npy
```

###### Steps to reproduce

1. use `onnx_graphsurgeon` to modify a  pyTorch model output like this

```
num_boxes_int = gs.Variable(name='num_boxes_int', dtype=np.int64)
num_boxes_out = gs.Variable(name='num_boxes_out', dtype=np.float32)
num_boxes_node = gs.Node(op="Shape",
                         inputs=[bbox_out],
                         outputs=[num_boxes_int], 
                         attrs={
                             'start':1,'end':2})
graph.nodes.append(num_boxes_node)
num_boxes_cast_node = gs.Node(op="Cast", 
                     inputs=[num_boxes_int], 
                     outputs=[num_boxes_out],
                    attrs={'to':int(onnx.TensorProto.FLOAT)})
graph.nodes.append(num_boxes_cast_node)
...
graph.outputs = [num_boxes_out, ...]
```

2. convert to openvino format `!mo --input_model {onnx_model_path} --input_shape [1,3,{input_height},{input_width}] --output_dir {openvino_dir}`. Check in the netron.app, it seems fine:
   [image]
3. convert to tensorflow

```
!openvino2tensorflow \
--model_path {openvino_dir}/{openvino_filename} \
--model_output_path {tf_output_dir} \
--weight_replacement_config {weight_replacement_config_path} \
--non_verbose \
--output_saved_model \
--output_no_quant_float32_tflite \
--output_float16_quant_tflite \
--output_full_integer_quant_tflite \
--output_dynamic_range_quant_tflite
```

4. got the error

```
WARNING: The numpy array (ndarray) cannot be specified as an output layer. Therefore, the tool outputs a sequentially numbered .npy binary file. .npy_file_path: tf_output/0.npy
```

5. check the generated tflite files in netron.app, it all looks normal but just doesn't have the `num_detections` as output
   [image]

###### My question:

What is the correct way to output a scalar value? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not supported with OpenVINO. However, you may refer to this [Github](https://github.com/PINTO0309/openvino2tensorflow) repository for the script to convert the OpenVINO Intermediate Representation (IR) model to TensorFlow format.